# Access Embedded Macro and Event Procedure

Tags: vba, ms-access

[image: Screen Shot]

I am trying to make basic msaccess form. And I created this save button through command button wizard. (Record Operations/ Save Record)

As you can see this save button's On_Click event =>>Embedded Macro.
I wanna write some additional code after insertion has occured.

`Private Sub Command28_Click()
MsgBox "Done!"
End Sub`

My question is: If On_Click=Macro; button save function works but msgbox code doesnt work. If On_Click=Procedure "Done!" message appears but save function doesnt work. How to work both of them (save function and message; in other words embedded macro and VBA code)

Comment: You can add the message box to the macro, convert the macro to vba, or call the subroutine through the macro.

Comment: @Warcupine Converting embedded macro to VBA and than writing some additional code. Yes! exactly what i need. Thanks a lot.   (Excell Top Menu/ Design/ Convert Form's Macros To Visual Basic)

Comment: Put `DoCmd.Save` as a new line before MsgBox "Done".